# Instantiating inner class in enclosing class - Ruby

Tags: ruby, exception

I am trying to create an instance of an inner class in the outer class in Ruby, in the following way,

`myclass.rb`

```
require 'mylibs'

class myClass
    class ClientNotInitializedError < StandardError
    end

    def myMethod
        if not @client raise ClientNotInitializedError.new
        #do stuff
    end
end
```

However this is failing in build where I am trying to throw the Exception. What am I doing wrong? 
I tried things like `self.ClientNotInitializedError.new` and `self::ClientNotInitializedError.new` but still no luck.

The `ClientNotInitializedError` is very specific to this class so I would like to keep it inside the class or at least in the same file.

Comment: "this is failing in build where I am trying to throw the Exception. What am I doing wrong?" – The error message is telling you what you did wrong. Since you didn't say what the error message is, there is no way we can help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've tried to run your code and got several mistakes:

a) **Class names must ALWAYS begin with a capital letter** (else you'll get the error: class/module name must be CONSTANT (SyntaxError))

b) You don't have a closing end block for your if statement where you're raising the error. This should work:

```
class MyClass
  class ClientNotInitializedError < StandardError; end

  def my_method
    raise ClientNotInitializedError.new unless @client
    #do stuff
  end
end

MyClass.new.my_method #=> will raise the appropriate error
```

I recommend you familiarize yourself with [Ruby's naming conventions.](https://github.com/bbatsov/ruby-style-guide#naming)

Comment: a) that was more of a rush to post the question
b) i missed the end here. i had it in code. it still bombed

that said, the syntax you are using i.e. `raise .. if not ..` seems to work whereas `if not .. raise .. end` didn't. i am surprised

Comment: I suggest you explain why you changed around the line `if not @client` (precedence). Stylistically, maybe `unless` rather than `if not`.

Comment: Oh, didn't pay particular attention on that. You're right Cary, I've changed it to unless.